# Given the win odds of a horse race are known plus other info such as top 3 place odds, calculate the 2nd/3rd/4th place odds for each horse.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, gambling

I have a problem where I am trying to calculate the place odds given win odds and other info such as top 3 place odds.

I have used Harville's method successfully to calc place odds given we know the win odds. However I am struggling completely with how to incorporate other information such as obtaining a more accurate 4th place probability if we know the odds of a horse finishing in the top 3.

Below is my attempt. It seems to be wrong based on my results (they seem off).

```
let calcPlaceOdds = () => {
let activeRunners = utils.getActiveRunners(odds);
for (let horseNumber of activeRunners) {
    let secondPlaceProbability = 0
    let thirdPlaceProbability = 0
    let fourthPlaceProbability = 0
    let horse = odds[horseNumber]
    const hasTop2 = horse.top2odds > 0
    const hasTop3 = horse.top3odds > 0
    const hasTop4 = horse.top4odds > 0
    for (let otherHorseNumber of activeRunners) {
        let other = odds[otherHorseNumber]
        if (horseNumber != otherHorseNumber && other.winOdds> 0) {
            let secondPlaceProbTemp = (1 / other.winOdds) * (1 / horse.winOdds) / (1 - (1 / other.winOdds));
            if(hasTop2) {
                secondPlaceProbTemp = (1/horse.top2odds - 1/horse.winOdds) / (activeRunners.length -1)
            }
            secondPlaceProbability += secondPlaceProbTemp
            for (let other2HorseNumber of activeRunners) {
                let other2 = odds[other2HorseNumber]
                if (horseNumber != other2HorseNumber && other2HorseNumber != otherHorseNumber && other2.winOdds> 0) {
                    let thirdPlaceProbTemp = secondPlaceProbTemp * (1 / other2.winOdds) / (1 - (1 / other.winOdds) - (1 / other2.winOdds));
                    if(hasTop3) {
                       thirdPlaceProbTemp = ((1 / horse.top3odds - 1 / horse.winOdds) / (Math.pow(activeRunners.length -1,2))) - secondPlaceProbTemp / (activeRunners.length-1)
                    }
                    thirdPlaceProbability += thirdPlaceProbTemp;
                    for (let other3HorseNumber of activeRunners) {
                        let other3 = odds[other3HorseNumber]
                        if (horseNumber !== other3HorseNumber &&
                            other3HorseNumber !== other2HorseNumber &&
                            other3HorseNumber !== otherHorseNumber &&
                            other2HorseNumber !== otherHorseNumber &&
                            other3.winOdds> 0) {
                            let fourthPlaceTemp = thirdPlaceProbTemp * (1 / other3.winOdds) / (1 - (1 / other.winOdds) - (1 / other2.winOdds) - (1 / other3.winOdds));

                            if(hasTop4) {
                               fourthPlaceTemp = ((1/horse.top4odds - 1/horse.winOdds) / (Math.pow(activeRunners.length -1,3))) - (secondPlaceProbTemp / (Math.pow(activeRunners.length -1,2))) - thirdPlaceProbTemp / (activeRunners.length-1);
                            }
                            fourthPlaceProbability += fourthPlaceTemp
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
             placeOdds[horseNumber] = {
               2ndPlaceProb: 1/secondPlaceProbability,
               3rdPlaceProb: 1/thirdPlaceProbability,
               4thPlaceProb: 1/fourthPlaceProbability}
        }
    }
```

Comment: MathSE is not the forum for computer code.

Comment: What you are saying is that you have a model (probability of a particular horse being first out of a particular subset is its "weight" divided by the total "weights" of the horses in the the subset, where the "weights" are proportional to  the probabilities of winning the original race derived from the original win odds) but also information (the place odds) telling you that your model is wrong.  Even if you adjust for this in sensible ways, it should not be a surprise if your end results seem off.

Comment: @Henry  A truly life changing comment there mate. Yes I am not surprised that it's off.

Comment: @user2661923  Playing my tiny violin for you :)